# Why I am getting Database Exception in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I created an android app which uses Firebase Database, custom model class and adapters. The app in debug state ran well, but when it was released it showed 'DatabaseException'. I checked each and every line of my code thoroughly but I am not able to find out a single error.

The error I get is:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: 
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.<init> (CustomClassMapper.java:11)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass (CustomClassMapper.java:12)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean (CustomClassMapper.java:4)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass (CustomClassMapper.java:4)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass (CustomClassMapper.java:6)
  at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue (DataSnapshot.java:6)
  at janabsmile.yuwashastra.Fragments.Activities$2.onDataChange (Activities.java:6)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent (ValueEventRegistration.java:2)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire (DataEvent.java:2)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run (EventRaiser.java:6)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8167)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:496)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Code snippets of Activites.java (Fragment)

```
public class Activities extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    TaskAdapter taskAdapter;
    List<Tasks> tasksList;
    LinearLayout layout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_updates, container, false);


        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        layout = view.findViewById(R.id.layout);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,true));
        tasksList = new ArrayList<>();
        taskAdapter = new TaskAdapter(getContext(), tasksList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(taskAdapter);

        readTasks();

        return view;
    }

    private void readTasks() {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("News").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                tasksList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Tasks tasks = snapshot.getValue(Tasks.class);
                    tasksList.add(tasks);
                }
                taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Code snippet of Tasks.java (Model Class)

```
public class Tasks{

    public String id;
    public String topic;
    public String description;

    public Tasks() {
    }

    public Tasks(String id, String topic, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.topic = topic;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTopic() {
        return topic;
    }

    public void setTopic(String topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

The TaskAdapter.java is:

```
public class TaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    private final Context mContext;
    private final List<Tasks> mTasks;

    private DatabaseReference mRef;

    public TaskAdapter(Context mContext, List<Tasks> mTasks) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mTasks = mTasks;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.task_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        FirebaseUser fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        Tasks task = mTasks.get(position);
        holder.topic.setText(task.getTopic());
        holder.description.setText(task.getDescription());

        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mRef.child("News").child(task.getId()).removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Deleted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                               notifyItemRemoved(position);
                               notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mTasks.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView topic;
        TextView description;
        Button delete;
        ProgressBar progressBar;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            topic = itemView.findViewById(R.id.topic);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
            progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        }
    }
}
```

This is how the data in the realtime database is stored:

[image: Realtime database]

Can anyone guide me out through this?

Comment: please add the full error

Comment: @PeterHaddad It is the complete error, shown in the stack trace.